# $('#slider').nivoSlider(); is not a function

Tags: jquery, web, slider, nivo-slider

First of all i have been looking at the similar question but without any results here is my problem.

I am able to set up the nivo slider perfectly fine locally, however when i copy and paste the EXACT same thing and im talking about both folder and possition in folders to my webhotel i get the following error:

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider(); is not a function
```

Ive been working for hours now with no result and its starting to piss me off :S

here are some images of my folder structure i have highlighted the spot of where the important files are:

**My index file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include 'includes/page.class.php';
$url = isset($_REQUEST['url']) ? $_REQUEST['url'] : null;
$page = ($url != null) ? new page($url) : new page();
?>
<html>
<head>

<link href="site/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  media="screen" />
<link href="site/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  media="screen" />
  <link href="themes/bar/bar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  media="screen" />
<link href="site/css/hint.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  media="screen" />
<link href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascripts/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascripts/kontakt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascripts/ommig.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascripts/projekter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascripts/android.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<title><?php echo $page->getTitle() ?>
</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="forside.php" id="mainsite">Forside</a></li>
          <li><a href="projekter.php" id="mainsite">Projekter</a></li>
          <li><a href="ommig.php" id="aboutme">Om mig</a></li>
          <li><a href="kontakt.php" id="mainsite">kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div id="page">
      <div id="content">
        <?php echo $page->loadPage() ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" />
        <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" /></a>
        <img src="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" />
        <img src="images/walle.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
    <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>
    <div id="footer">
      <hr>
      <div id="credits">
        <p style="text-align: center;">
          <b>&copy; Design by | Marc Rasmussen</b>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: My folder that contains my website]

**Firebug message**

[image]

Comment: "jQuery is not defined" is a scary string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should source `jQuery` before `nivoSlider`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

To me the problem is that you're using the slide **before** requiring jQuery.

This

```
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! ... I hate when that happens